# How to validate a value against an existing field

Tags: 7, forms

I'm doing some custom stuff with programmatically saving fields with EMW:

```
$wrapper->my_field->set('my_value');
```

Problem is, this doesn't validate before trying to save the field. How can I validate the value against the field before trying to save it?

Comment: Are you trying to validate the value against the field of the entity you saved before? Is it an edit action?

Comment: Yes it's editing, but whether it's editing or a new entity I don't see the difference.

Comment: Yes, i just misunderstood the question. zhilevan is right, you have to add your custom validations using for example some regular expressions etc depending on what you need for your field.

Answer (score 0):

install [entity_validator](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_validator) module .

> Unlike Drupal 8, Drupal 7 has not validation for entity objects what
>   so ever. One of your modules can create a node object without any
>   title or a language and you don't want that.

for drupal 8 Use [Entity Validation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/entity-validation-api-overview) before save your fields.

as a example

```
 $violations = $typed_data->validate();
    $definition = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->addConstraint('Range', ['min' => 5]);
    $typed_data = \Drupal::typedDataManager()->create($definition, 10);
  if ($violations->count() == 0) { // this means there is not any validation error
     // save Entity
  }
```

Comment: @Smalution Oops, so there is no convenient way, you can write your own custom validator and check items before saving or wait for entity wrapper exceptions :D

Comment: Whaaat? How does Drupal itself do it? There must be a function somewhere!

Comment: @Chris Unlike Drupal 8, Drupal 7 has not validation for entity objects what so ever.

Comment: @Smalution Check the Answer again, I update it.